# Show all rows from employees master table even when applying filters after joining with Sales Table

Tags: join, databricks-sql

I have two tables Employee Master and Sales Fact with below structurs

**Employee master:**

| empId | empName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Jack |
| 2 | John |
| 3 | Luke |

**Sales Fact:**

| empId | SalesDate | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-10-12 | 100 |
| 2 | 2023-10-23 | 200 |
| 1 | 2023-11-12 | 100 |
| 3 | 2023-11-23 | 200 |
| 2 | 2023-12-12 | 100 |
| 3 | 2023-12-23 | 200 |

When I join these two tables and filter for a particular month, the employees who have not made any sales on that month are not shown. (Eg: When I filter for October 2023 only 1 and 2 are shown, when I filter for November 2023, only 1 and 3 are shown)

But my requirement is that I need to create a view to show all the employees for each month regardless of whether they have made a sale or not. (Eg: When I filter for October 2023 then I want all 3 employees and the amount should be NULLfor empId 3)

My current solution is to join these two tables every month and insert the data into a new table having one extra MonthYear column which is what I use for filter. But I have to run this monthly which is what I want to avoid

Note: Recursive CTEs are not avaliable in my databricks workspace

Here are the codes to create and insert values for these tables:

```
-- Create the table
CREATE TABLE employeeMaster (
    empId INT,
    empName STRING
);

-- Insert the values into the table
INSERT INTO employees VALUES
(1, 'Jack'),
(2, 'John'),
(3, 'Luke');
```

```
-- Create the table
CREATE TABLE sales (
    empId INT,
    SalesDate DATE,
    Amount INT
);

-- Insert the values into the table
INSERT INTO salesFact VALUES
(1, '2023-10-12', 100),
(2, '2023-10-23', 200),
(1, '2023-11-12', 100),
(3, '2023-11-23', 200),
(2, '2023-12-12', 100),
(3, '2023-12-23', 200);
```

Comment: Is there a guarantee of at least a sale by *someone* every month?

Comment: Yes. For every month there will be at least one employee who has made a sale

Comment: Names of table created and table names inserted into do not agree. I have assumed the longer names in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery to return all the months (for which there is at least 1 sale), then cross join to employee to get all combos of employee and months and finally left join to sales:

```
select
  e.empId,
  e.empName,
  mths.mth,
  sum(s.amount) total_amount
from (select distinct date(date_trunc('MONTH', SalesDate)) mth from salesFact) mths
cross join employeeMaster e
left join salesFact s on s.empId = e.empId 
  and date(date_trunc('MONTH', s.SalesDate)) = mths.mth
group by 1, 2, 3
order by 3, 1
```

See [live demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/B7_1CMqZ).

---

If you want a zero instead of a `null` for total amounts where there is no sale for the month for an employee, use

```
coalesce(sum(s.amount), 0) total_amount
```